# How to give myself permission to edit the locked hosts file on MacOS Mojave?

Tags: mojave, permission, hosts

I am logged in with my admin account, which is my only account on this computer. I checked under preferences and it says "admin".

I have located the file here:

```
/private/etc/hosts
```

When I go to getinfo, it looks like the file is not locked. I also added myself and for good measure everyone with r&w permissions:

[image]

Still, when I open it and try to edit it, it says I have no permission:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. Additionally, disabling SIP just to edit the hosts file is really not good measure. A commandline "sudo" would have helped.

Comment: I can edit the hosts file using BBEdit, (a highly recommended text editor).